# Array of items as contextual filter in Views

Tags: 7, nodes, users, views

I need to create a View which displays content of users that their username should be passed as contextual filter. The number of parameters (usernames) are not specified but the View must include every username that is passed via url, as an example

```
example.com/some-path/user1
example.com/some-path/user1/user2
example.com/some-path/user3/user2/user12
```

the view must include all of pathes like the above ones and filter the contents but I really have no idea how to implement this using Views UI. I can do this programmatically by looping through each component of the url but I don't want to use such methods.

Comment: why dont you use comma seperation for user name like "example.com/some-path/user3,user2,user12" ?

Comment: @VimalGoradiya how do I config the View??

Comment: need to add Content: Author relationship and in contextual filter need add User: Name. Where you can pass multiple username  seperated by comma.

Comment: I already did this before but I can't get the results when I type `user1,user2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to check "Allow multiple values" true by click on **More** toggle part of contextual filters field works well.

example.com/some-path/user3,user2,user12